# Chrome extension's service worker not starting on event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am creating an extension using manifest V3 with a service worker that is set to listen for "webRequest.onBeforeRequest"
`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(requestDetails) { . . . }, { urls: ['<all_urls>'] }, ['requestBody']);`

On my personal machine (windows), the extension works as expected and the service worker starts whenever there is a web request in any of the tabs.

However, on our work machines (mac), the web requests do not automatically start the service worker. If I manually start it, it receives the events and functions properly, but as soon as it is stopped due to being idle, it does not re-start on the next web request. If I go to "chrome://serviceworker-internals/", I can see that the service worker is still registered, but is stopped.

My only way of keep the extension functioning has been to keep the developer tools page for the service worker open (via inspecting it), so that it continues to work by simply never stopping.

Is there something specific that I need to to do for mac OS or are there any settings or policies that can limit what events a stopped service-worker can listen for?

Comment: It's a [known bug](https://crbug.com/1024211) so don't use ManifestV3 until it's fixed.

Comment: Alarming that this bug stops basic functionality, has been around for more than 2 years, and still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Also, here's a somewhat hacky workaround I use: I trigger the requests that I am listening to via `webRequest` in my extension, so I know exactly when the requests will take place. I manually wake up the service worker before each request with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Wake up please')` from my content script and added `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(console.log)` in my service worker. This works like a charm, but it shouldn't be needed in the first place...

Comment: I also suppose you could make a content script that runs on each page you visit that calls `chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Wake up please')` in a `setTimeout` loop (about every 15 seconds should do) so that the service worker will always be active; however, at that point, you might as well use Manifest V2.

Comment: Actually, according to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/, `the background script will not unload until all message ports have shut.` Thus, instead of a `sendMessage` on a loop like I said before, you can open a connection to your service worker in some content script and that will force it to stay open.

Answer (score 4):

Would have put this in the comments, but don't have enough reputation to comment. I tried to solve this by having a setTimeout loop every 10 seconds (which is also something Gregory Conrad suggested in the comments) but unfortunately this didn't work the service worker still went inactive. In the comments someone said this is a known bug, but it seems like it might not be a bug, it could be intentional: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2021/12/chrome-users-beware-manifest-v3-deceitful-and-threatening. As the link says, service workers make it harder for browser extensions such as AdBlock to work as effectively, something which would benefit Google as they run a major internet advertising network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30840164)

Comment: I beg to differ. The question was asking if there was any way to prevent a service worker from stopping listening for webRequests. In my answer I say that there is not a known way to stop this behavior as it in Manifest V3 it is intended that browser extensions not be able to continually listen for webRequests.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
Inserting code like the following seems to fix the problem.
If I didn't set the callback function, it didn't work.

```
//content_script.js

var wakeup = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('ping', function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
        wakeup();
    }, 1000);
}
wakeup();

//background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){

    if( request == "ping" ){
        console.log(request);
        sendResponse("pong");
        return;
    }

    sendResponse();
});
```

Comment: Hi @tekka - I added this in content_script.js but still the service worker goes 'inactive'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @MatheswaranKanagarajan. I added code of background.js. Please try it.